# using each_with_index and adding values with corresponding index for a new array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, loops, indexing

ruby newbie here. i need to use the each_with_index function to create a new array which adds values to their corresponding index. below is what I believe is the solution, but of course, it doesn't work. I'm sure even that 'p' to print the values is unnecessary too.

```
def add_value_and_index(a)
  a.each_with_index do |value, index|
    p #{value} + #{index}"
  end
end
```

here are the specs:

```
describe '#add_value_and_index' do
  it "returns a new array composed of the value + index of each element in the former" do
    expect( add_value_and_index([2,1,0]) ).to eq([2,2,2])
  end
end
```

Comment: it be better to use `map.with_index`

Comment: hmm. current part of the curriculum isn't using that function yet. i'm limited to these tools at the moment as an intro to loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` to accually return the results:

```
def add_value_and_index(array)
  array.map.with_index { |value, index| value + index }
end
```

If the curriculum isn't using `map` yet, you can create a new array and add the sums to that in each iteration:

```
def add_value_and_index(array)
  result = []
  array.each_with_index { |value, index| result << value + index }
  result
end
```

I would not use that second example in production, since it is verbose and hard to read.

Comment: what if i was restricted from using .map? and had to use each_with_index?

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate it. This syntax hasn't been reviewed yet in my course, but it seems the most compliant to my restrictions. Thank you!